# Run UPDATE query by a custom order

Tags: mysql, sql-update, increment

Is there a way to update all records in the table by a specific custom order? I specifically mean a situation, when the actual order comes from the 'outside' (eg as POST value).

For example, have a table

```
   id | title | order_idx
   ----------------------
    1 | lorem | 1
    2 | ipsum | 2
    3 | dolor | 3
```

I have a form that submits a hidden field, carrying ID values in this order: 2, 3, 1
I want to update the table to add incremental number to order_idx in each next row, going by the ID order served by the form field. So in this case, end result should look like this:

```
   id | title | order_idx
   ----------------------
    1 | lorem | 3
    2 | ipsum | 1
    3 | dolor | 2
```

Can this be done in a single UPDATE query somehow as opposed to running 3 queries (each including WHERE clause) in a php loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional expressions in assignment statements, like so:

```
UPDATE t 
SET x = CASE 
WHEN 2 THEN 1 
WHEN 3 THEN 2 
WHEN 1 THEN 3
ELSE x
WHERE ....
```

parameterized:

```
UPDATE t 
SET x = CASE 
WHEN ? THEN 1 
WHEN ? THEN 2 
WHEN ? THEN 3
ELSE x
WHERE ....
```

In either case, the query will most likely need constructed dynamically to account for a varying number of items to order.

---

Since your comment indicates potentially hundreds...
MySQL has a limit to query length [(reference)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html).

For a large number, I would start recommending a different approach.

```
Step 1) CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `newOrder` (id INT, new_order_idx INT);
Step 2) INSERT id's and their new order into the temp table.
Step 3) UPDATE t INNER JOIN newOrder AS n ON t.id = n.id SET t.order_idx = n.new_order_idx WHERE ...
Step 4) DROP TEMPORARY TABLE newOrder;
```

The process itself is no longer a single query; but the UPDATE is.

---

Note: If you have a unique key involving `order_idx` I am entirely sure either of these would work. Occasions when I have needed to maintain uniqueness, the usual solution is to shift the records to be adjusted to a completely different range in one step, and then to their new positions in a second one. (Something like `UPDATE t SET order_idx = -1 * order_idx WHERE ...` would work as a pre-Step 3 range shift in the second part of this answer.)

Comment: Thanks for a tip. Yeah, I have no problem with constructing the query dynamically. I'd say better this than running individual queries in a loop. Example is 3 rows but in reality there could be hundreds

Answer (score 0):

Use **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** like below:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, order_idx) VALUES (1,3),(2,1),(3,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE order_idx=VALUES(order_idx);
```

So you can set **order_idx** dynamically for every row:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, order_idx) 
VALUES (1,order_list[0]),(2,order_list[1]),(3,order_list[2])
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE order_idx=VALUES(order_idx);
```